# websocket javascript request for x-lite or Bria soft phone

Tags: javascript, websocket, sip

I'd like create a web application which is communicating with X-lite SIP phone. I found API documentation Click [here](http://www.counterpath.com/assets/product_documents/Bria_Desktop_API_R10.pdf?agreeNowdownload=Download+API) but I don't understand how should I parsed the data for request. For example GET /status "phone". I know use just simple request as GET /showHistory. Thanks for any advice.

```
function WebSocketTest(){
    var ws = new WebSocket("wss://cpclientapi.softphone.com:9002/counterpath/socketapi/v1");

    ws.onopen = function (event) {
        //here I dont know how to write xml request from documentation
        //for example GET /status "phone"
        ws.send('GET /showHistory');
    };
    ws.onerror = function(error){
        console.log('Error detected: ' + error);
    }
    ws.onmessage = function(messageEvent) {
        if (typeof messageEvent.data === "string"){
            console.log("received text data from the server: " + messageEvent.data);
        } else if (messageEvent.data instanceof Blob){
            console.log("Blob data received")
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using localhost:9002

```
function WebSocketTest(){
    var ws = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:9002/counterpath/socketapi/v1");

    ws.onopen = function (event) {
        //here I dont know how to write xml request from documentation
        //for example GET /status "phone"
        ws.send('GET /showHistory');
    };
    ws.onerror = function(error){
        console.log('Error detected: ' + error);
    }
    ws.onmessage = function(messageEvent) {
        if (typeof messageEvent.data === "string"){
            console.log("received text data from the server: " + messageEvent.data);
        } else if (messageEvent.data instanceof Blob){
            console.log("Blob data received")
        }
    };
}
```